plugin_build_tool doesn't find default QGIS Plugin directory
I've had a working setup with QGIS 3.28.11 (OSGeo4W installation) and plugin_build_tool (installed via pip install pb_tool in the OSGeo4W Shell to deploy a QGIS Plugin I'm developing. Updating the QGIS version somehow messed this setup up. I had to reinstall plugin_build_tool but now it doesn't find the QGIS plugin directory. This is still in the default location (C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins) - as it used to be, I haven't changed anything there. Yet I do get the following error, when running pbt deploy:
Unable to determine location of your QGIS Plugin directory.
        Make sure your QGIS environment is setup properly for development and Python
        has access to the PyQt5.QtCore module or specify plugin_path in your pb_tool.cfg.
Unable to determine where to deploy your plugin

I'm aware that I can add the plugin_path to the pb_tool.cfg file (deploy then works), but that wasn't necessary before and I'd rather avoid that and have a working default path.
Is there a way to check, which folder pbt is trying to use by default?
Is this a known problem? (versions: pb_tool-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl, QGIS 3.34.6 LTR, 3.36 current)
I assume, pb_tool works with the variable QGIS_PLUGINPATH (mentioned in this old issue), but I don't know where this is set and how I can modify it.
